# Comparing time complexity for two solutions for same python problem statement

Tags: python, optimization, time-complexity

We have first solution as :

```
class Solution:
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        return len(nums) != len(set(nums))
```

Ans second approach for the same problem as :

```
class Solution(object):
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
        hset = set()
        for idx in nums:
            if idx in hset:
                return True
            else:
                hset.add(idx)
```

**Question : Both having time complexity equal to O(N), but actual time taken has major difference between two approaches. Why is this the case ?**

Comment: Because one solution mostly relies on the work being done in C and the other relies much more on work in python

Comment: Ah, so big o notation only tells us half story

Comment: Algorithmic complexity describes the way that algorithms *scale*